# Prove that the volume of the tetrahedron whose coterminus edges are $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ is given by $\frac{1}{6}\vec{a}.(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})$

Tags: vectors

Prove that the volume of the tetrahedron whose coterminus edges are $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ is given by $\frac{1}{6}\vec{a}.(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})$

---

I could not prove it.Please help me.

Comment: What is $a \cdot b \times c$ the volume of? Can you cut that shape in six to form the tetrahedron?

Comment: use a.bxc as cyclic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the plane formed by $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ as base, the usual formula gives us $V={1\over3}A_{base}h$ where $A_{base}$ is the base triangle area and $h$ is the height with respect to the base plane.

The cross product $\vec{b}\times\vec{c}$ gives you a magnitude of 2 times the area of $A_{base}$ and a vector in the same direction as the height, while the dot product basically project $\vec{a}$ onto the height vector and thus gives you the magnitude of the height $h$.

Hence ${1\over6}\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})={1\over6}2A_{base}h={1\over3}A_{base}h=V$.