# The vector $\vec{v}$ perpendicular to the plane of the triangle $ABC$ drawn from the origin $O$

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $A(\vec{a}), B(\vec{b})$ and $C(\vec{c})$ be three non-collinear points. Prove that the vector $\vec{v}$ perpendicular to the plane of the triangle $ABC$ drawn from the origin $O$ is given by $\vec{v}=\pm\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})\cdot\dfrac{(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}+\vec{b}\times\vec{c}+\vec{c}\times\vec{a})}{4\Delta^2}$ where $\vec{\Delta}$ is the vector area of the triangle $ABC.$

---

$\vec{\Delta}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{b}-\vec{a})\times(\vec{c}-\vec{a})=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}+\vec{b}\times\vec{c}+\vec{c}\times\vec{a})$
$\Delta^2=\frac{1}{4}(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}).(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})+(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}).(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})+(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}).(\vec{c}\times\vec{a})+(\vec{b}\times\vec{c}).(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})+(\vec{b}\times\vec{c}).(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})+(\vec{b}\times\vec{c}).(\vec{c}\times\vec{a})+(\vec{c}\times\vec{a}).(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})+(\vec{c}\times\vec{a}).(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})+(\vec{c}\times\vec{a}).(\vec{c}\times\vec{a})$

But I don't know how to derive the required relation. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably know that the vector $(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}+\vec{b}\times\vec{c}+\vec{c}\times\vec{a})$ is perpendicular to the plane of the triangle. SO the vector $\vec{r}$ must be along this vector only and hence we write $$\vec{r}=\lambda (\vec{a}\times\vec{b}+\vec{b}\times\vec{c}+\vec{c}\times\vec{a})$$

As you probably remember from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521083/prove-that-the-volume-of-the-tetrahedron-whose-coterminus-edges-are-veca-ve) question, the volume of the tetrahedron whose coterminus edges are $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ is given by $\frac{1}{6}\vec{a}.(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})$ . This volume can also be expressed as $\frac 13 \Delta|\vec{r}| $ and hence we get that $$|\vec{r}|={[\space\vec{a} \space\space\vec{b}\space\space \vec{c}\space]\over 2\Delta^2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: In the second line of the second para of your answer,should not it be,This volume can also be expressed as $\frac{1}{3}\Delta|\vec{r}|$,rest i understood,Sir.@G-man

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia yes, edited. And in the future please refrain from calling me sir, since we are of an age(probably).